# Convert a multidimensional array into simpler form

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as shown below,
How to convert the above array1 into array2 form?

array1

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 500 GB
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100 GB
    )

 )
```

array2

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 500 GB
        [1] => 100 GB
 )
```

Comment: For a simple array like that with just a single element, array_column()

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourArray = [[0 => '500 GB'], [0 => '100 GB'], [1 => '200 GB']];
$result = array_filter(
    array_map(
    function($element) {
        if (isset($element[0])) {
            return $element[0];
        }

        return;
    },
    $yourArray
    ),
    function($element) {
        return $element !== null;
    }
);

echo var_dump($result); // array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "500 GB" [1]=> string(6) "100 GB" }
```

This will work only with php >= 5.4 (because of array short syntax). If you're running on older versione, just substitute `[]` with `array()`

### Explaination

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is used to exclude certain values from an array (by using a callback function). In this case, `NULL` values that you get from `array_map`.
 
[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is used to apply a function to "transform" your array. In particular it applies a function to each array element and returns that element after function application.

Comment: it's better to check whether `$element[0]` exists before returning it, to avoid undefined variable warning

Comment: @Raptor: yes, of course

Comment: $tempArray = array(0=>array(0=>"500 GB"), 1=>array(0=>"100 GB"));
    $flat = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tempArray)), 0);